# Detect if app is installed on desktop from browser web page

Tags: javascript, windows, browser

I am trying to create a page that will redirect to download page if it detects the user does not have the app installed this is for windows and if installed will redirect to the app.

I have implemented the custom URI with like myapp:// but trying to figure out how to detect from any browser if the app is installed on windows/mac/linux.

Comment: You can register a protocol handler with windows check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries ([this one f.e.](https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection)) that say they can detect custom protocols, but I haven't found any that work with the latest version of Firefox.

The most reliable (chrome, edge, firefox, ie 11) and easy way I've found is simply create a hidden iframe.
Then you can just put a download button on the same page.

```css
iframe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="ms-calculator://"></iframe>
<iframe src="nonexistentscheme://"></iframe>
<a href="">Download</a>
```

**NOTE:**
Firefox only allows the dialogue every 10 seconds.

EDIT: Also works in IE 11

Comment: Is there no way where it detects and can auto redirect without on screen intervention ?

If exists opens if not forward to download page.

Comment: you can probably subscribe to the load event of the iframe and redirect then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let userPromptedToOpenDesktopApp = false;
    window.onblur = () => { userPromptedToOpenDesktopApp = true };

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!userPromptedToOpenDesktopApp) {
            window.location = "https://myapp.com";
        }
    }, 1000);

    window.location = "myapp://";
}
```

Idea goes:

WHEN `window.location = "myapp://"` runs,

THEN IF desktop app is installed, the browser will show modal, thus the window.onblur function kicks in.

ELSE the `if` check in the `setTimeout` function passes, and the user gets redirected to the website.

*Minor assumption: the original post expects for this to happen on page load, but the code can be run anywhere of course, e.g. on button click.*